# Design a REST api which will fetch results from multiple apis using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest

Am trying to design a REST api which will throw an aggregated response from multiple apis.

Following is the NodeJS code am trying to execute -

```
Pseudo Code start
//endpoint to be called from a browser / REST client 

router.get('/api/v1/getItems', (req, response, next) => {

var result = {} // hold the aggregated response from multiple apis
    //internally fire another endpoint & add the response over to the var result
 http.get(endpoint 1, function(resp){
 add response to result})
 http.get(endpoint 2, function(resp){
 add response to result
})
return response.json(result);
}

Pseudo Code end


// endpoint to be called from the browser or REST Client.
router.get('/api/v1/getItems', (req, response, next) => {
  var results = {};

// Nested Endpoint 1
  var optionsgetmsg = {
    host : 'host.domain.com', // tthe domain name
    port : 9043,
    path : '/services/itemdata', // the rest of the url
    method : 'GET' // do GET
};

//child endpoint
  var reqGet = http.request(optionsgetmsg, function(res) {

    res.on('data', function(d) {

        console.log("d "+ d); // child response
        results.itemdata = d;
        return response.send(results);
        //process.stdout.write(d);

    });

    res.on('end', function(d){

    })


  });
  reqGet.end();
  reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
      console.error(e);
  });
});
```

The result in the above case should be the output 'd'. The output 'd' is the response from the child endpoint.

Actual result am getting is an empty object. {}

Comment: I suggest you either use a more friendly http client that will give you serialized results, or read up on streams - https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_consumers

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. Please elloborate your problem / question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending JSON, you must set the headers correctly and the response:

```
 //child endpoint
var reqGet = http.request(optionsgetmsg, function(res) {

res.on('data', function(d) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var results = d;
    response.send(JSON.stringify(results));

});
```

It is unclear as to what exactly you are asking for.